# Accessing web service on routed (without NAT) network

Tags: router, dns, routing, nat

I have network topology where I use two routers: R1 and R2. R1 has NAT enabled because my ISP allows only to connect one IP. R2 has NAT disabled because I'm planning to extend my network in the future and I want to be able to communicate between all connected devices from each other and do not want to mess with virtual servers, dmz etc. Everything is working as expected and I can access the internet from my PC. The only thing that I am unable to access from PC is management web interface for router R1. When I connect PC directly to R1 without R2 web intterface is accessible with no problems, but when PC is connected to R1 via R2 it is not. One thing that I noticed on R1 is that there is option called "Remote Management IP Address" which basically allows one IP to manage R1 from WAN port. I have tried set this option to 192.168.1.10 but it did not helped. My assumption is that R1 does not allow management from another network as it's directly connected 192.168.3.3/24. As I said before R2 has NAT disabled and thus R1 sees packets comming from PC with their original source address and does not allows managing. When I switched R2 to use NAT I was able to access web interface on 192.168.3.3. I think there is not another workaround just using NAT, but if anyone have better idea I would be glad.

Topology:

```
     internet
       /|\
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
       \|/ WAN
   my_isp_wireless_router
       /|\ LAN: 172.27.7.1/24
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
       \|/ WAN: 172.27.7.10/24(DHCP)
       R1
       /|\ LAN: 192.168.3.3/24
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
       \|/ WAN: 192.168.3.1/24
       R2
       /|\ LAN: 192.168.1.1/24
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
       \|/ 192.168.1.10/24(DHCP)
       PC
```

Here are my settings:

#### Router 1 (R1)

- NAT is enabled
- Firewall is disabled
- Added static route to `192.168.1.0/24` via `192.168.3.1`
- **Default GW:** `172.27.7.1`
- **DNS:** `172.27.7.1`

#### Router 2 (R2)

- NAT is disabled
- Firewall is disabled
- **Default GW:** `192.168.3.3`
- **DNS:** `192.168.3.3`, `8.8.8.8`

#### PC

- **Default GW:** `192.168.1.1`
- **DNS:** `192.168.1.1`

Here are my observations:

#### Working:

- **PC:** `ping 192.168.3.3`
- **R2:** `telnet 192.168.3.3 80`
- **PC:** `telnet www.google.com 80`

#### Does not work:

- **PC:** `telnet 192.168.3.3 80`
- **PC:** `traceroute 192.168.3.3`

#### Questions:

1. Why I am unable to access Router 1 web admin page from PC? when I direct connect PC to Router 2 (without Router 1) I can access this page without problems.
2. On Router 2 which settings for DHCP is the best solution:

   - **DNS:** 192.168.1.1
   - **DNS:** 192.168.3.3
   - **DNS:** 172.27.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your router is blocking requests to its admin interface when they don’t originate from the local network, `192.168.3.0/24`. It’s a popular (non-)security feature. But you already guessed that.

Instead, the question is: Why do you even need multiple subnets? Surely, you won’t ever use more than 253 devices. If it’s about traffic accounting, it can also be done with a transparent bridge. If it’s about cable length, use switches.

Comment: When I have AP in router mode it allows me to use e.g. traffic shaping and another cool features. Switching it to bridge mode I lost all of those. But this is probably one possible option for now

Comment: Traffic shaping is meaningless anyway unless it knows your upload bandwidth. So unless you manually entered it, it doesn’t do anything anyway. These things are better suited for the “edge” router.